# When should i use Throws Exception?

Tags: java

when should i use ***"Throws Exception"*** in my program?I see this with these classes sometime:***InputStreamReader*** ,***BufferedReader*** class .But I dont see this with ***FileReader*** and ***FileWriter*** class .Again i see it with ***FileInputStream*** and ***FileOutputStream.***
When i dont use it shows error in code .Why is it needed ?
This has made me confused when to use it and which sort of case i should use it.I m new to java programming.

**used here :**

```
import java.io.*;  

class C{  
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{  
FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream("hlw.java");  
FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream("M.java");  
int i=0;  
while((i=fin.read())!=-1){  
fout.write((byte)i);  
}  
fin.close();  
fout.close();
}  
}
```

**Not used Here**

```
import java.io.*;  
class Simple{  
 public static void main(String args[]){  
  try{  
   FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("abc.txt");  
   fw.write("my name is sachin");  
   fw.close();  
  }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}  
  System.out.println("success");  
 }  
}
```

Comment: You should **never** use `throws Exception`. You should both `throw` and handle **specific` exceptions only. It is the usage of `throws Exception` that has led to the uselessness of checked exceptions.

Comment: *"when should i use "Throws Exception" in my program?"* If possible: never. Always try to use specific exceptions, not the general `Exception` class.

Comment: Throwing exceptions is useful, it is only using it wrong that is wrong.

Comment: You see this often on MCVE snippets which don't bother with exception handling just for brevity sake. Don't get mislead by this. On the other hand, merely printing the exception and continuing the code as if nothing exceptional happened is worse than letting it go via throws.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare checked exceptions in the `throws` clause of your method when there are code paths from which an exception could be thrown *outside* your function.

When there is a `try`/`catch` block, an exception stays inside your function, so there is no need to use `throws` clause.

In your first example, on the other hand, you do not have a `try`/`catch`, so there is a code path that throws `IOException`, a checked exception, outside the function. That is what makes `throws` clause necessary.

**Note:** You should use `throws` clause with the *specific* exception types, describing the exceptions that your method can throw. Using `throws Exception` is not a good idea, because it defeats the purpose of declaring thrown exceptions in the first place by making all callers catch all types of exceptions, even though your method would never throw them.

Comment: Can i use try catch instead of throws exception?

Comment: @MaizerePathak.Nepal Absolutely. If you know how to handle an exception thrown by a method that you call, you should catch it, and not declare it in `throws` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You <strike>should</strike> may use it when :

- You have created a custom Exception, and want to throw it, as per certain conditions.
- You are too lazy to handle exceptions and want to pass them on.

But one should mostly try to handle them using the try-catch block.

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR: You should **never** use `throws Exception`

Declaring that your method throws *some sort* of `Exception` is next to useless. It also forces the even more unpleasant:

```
try {
    //stuff
} catch(Exception e) {
    //what now?
}
```

How do you handle "an error of some unknown sort"?

So your method should read `throws IOException` - this says that your method may encounter an IO issue.

This tells the caller that they may have to handle the case where there is an IO problem, this caller can then:

- ask the user to select another file
- select a default file
- exit with an error

But that is up to the *caller*.

So you should "[throw early, catch late](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/231057/exceptions-why-throw-early-why-catch-late)", i.e. the system should throw up an exception *as soon as* an error is encountered. And you should *keep rethrowing* until you end up somewhere that the error can be usefully handled.

As an example:

1. the user selects a file
2. the handler is triggered
3. the handler calls some file loading API
4. the API reads the file
5. ERROR

The only useful place that the exception can be handled, is at 1., as here the user can be asked to select a different file. At any other point, there is unlikely to be a useful action that can be taken.